# Determinant of block covariance matrix

Tags: determinants

I wonder how to express the determinant of a block covariance matrix. For example, I have a covariance matrix

$\Sigma=\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    \Sigma_1 & \Sigma_{12} \\
     \Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_2  \\
  \end{array}
\right]$

where $\Sigma_1\in\mathbb{R}^{n_1}\times\mathbb{R}^{n_1}$,  $\Sigma_2\in\mathbb{R}^{n_2}\times\mathbb{R}^{n_2}$ and hence  $\Sigma_{12}=\Sigma_{21}^\intercal\in\mathbb{R}^{n_1}\times\mathbb{R}^{n_2}$.

Can I express the denterminant of $\Sigma$ in terms of the 3 blocks? That is:

$|\Sigma|=f(\Sigma_1,\Sigma_2,\Sigma_{12})$

I guess it is somehow related to Schur Complement, I am  still studying..

Comment: You might consider checking wikipedia before posting to MO. For example, I think this might answer your question:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A well-known block determinant formula: if $\Sigma_1$ is invertible,
$$\det \Sigma = \det(\Sigma_1) \det(\Sigma_2 - \Sigma_{21} \Sigma_1^{-1} \Sigma_{12})$$ (and a similar formula if $\Sigma_2$ is invertible).

Comment: This is called *Schur complement formula*. The Schur complement of $\Sigma_1$ in $\Sigma$ is precisely $\Sigma_2-\Sigma_{21}\Sigma_1^{-1}\Sigma_{12}$.